# Freya crashes when exiting full-screen from youtube

Tags: google-chrome, midori, firefox, crash

As I exit out of full-screen from youtube, the picture on the computer is frozen. I can still hear the audio and the cursor can move but I cannot interact with the OS and the screen seems to be frozen. This has happened several times, it does not happen every time but enough to frustrate me.

Comment: me too its crash every time i want to watch youtube and other things now i use opera but please fix it ps.... iam so exited about elemantary os 0.4 loki :D

Answer (score 2):

I think both Chrome and Firefox use PPAPI, the pepper flash plugin so could be a compatibility issue with that. I would try looking in ~/.xsession-errors or ~/.xsession-errors.old if you have had to reboot.

Also if you have an Intel display adapter then try enabling "sna" as the Acceleration Method, it fixes a lot of video issues with some Intel chipsets in Ubuntu based distro's. Here's a link on how to do it.

http://www.apolitech.com/2016/01/how-to-solve-video-tearing-on-intel.html